# Android Espresso testing: how test an activity's onNewIntent?

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-espresso

I'm wondering if there's a way to test an Activiy **onNewIntent()** method, I want to test launching an activity with the flag single top set and test some behaviour, how can this be achieved with espresso?

Answer (score 6):

**Calling it directly:**

When you override `onNewIntent()` in your activity, you can make it public:

```
   @Override
    public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
    }
```

that way you can actually call it directly:

```
activityTestRule.getActivity().onNewIntent(new Intent())
```

This actually works, but it's not too good because you are calling the method from the testing app thread. If calling `onNewIntent()` will cause any changes on the UI you will get an exception because only the thread that created the view can change it. To fix this you can force running on the UI thread

```
activityTestRule.getActivity().runOnUiThread(() -> {
    activityTestRule.getActivity().onNewIntent(new Intent()));
});
```

This would allow you to test the `onNewIntent()` method of your activity.

**A better way:**

By the way you phrased your question, you also want to check some behaviour from the activity being defined as `singleTop`. Instead of calling the method directly, you can launch an intent that actually should trigger `onNewIntent()` in the activity under test:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(activityTestRule.getActivity().getApplicationContext(), ActivityUnderTest.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext().startActivity(intent));
```

This should end up calling `onNewIntent()` of the activity under test as long as it's defined as `singleTop`, otherwise it will start a new activity instance.

Comment: It does not work with AppCompatActivity, onNewIntent() as a protected access.

Comment: @Stéphane You can increase the visibility of the method to public when you override it. But I still think that launching a new intent in the test it's a better way to do it.

Comment: The last tip worked, thanks! Invoking InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation()
        .callActivityOnNewIntent doesn't trigger the call to onResume

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the `ActivityTestRule`, how about something like this?

```
Intents.init();
Intent intent = // Build your intent

rule.launchActivity(intent);

// Assertions    

Intents.release()
```

I'm not actually an Espresso user, but I'm assuming that will launch your activity and `onNewIntent()` will be called. Then make your assertions.

Note: this is using the Espresso Intents library, designed for this purpose.
`androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:2.2.2'`

Comment: Thanks, it works fine but shows me an error:couldn't launch intent intent within 45 seconds. Perhaps the main thread has not gone idle within a reasonable amount of time?

Comment: Espresso Intents was designed to deal with intents sent **out** by the application under test. There's no need to use it here. You can read it in the [intro](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/intents.html)